# android view animaiton on a path

Tags: java, android, animation

i am trying to make a 2d animation and i want an image to go on the brown path in the back ground. i am using `ValueAnimator` for this,

[That is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XppPq.png)

here is the code for the first part of the animation:

```
anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f,400f);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
        {
            value = (Float)animation.getAnimatedValue();

            if(soldier.getX()<400f)
                soldier.setX(value);
        }
    });
```

when its done setting the image's x value i cant figure out an efficient way to start making it change the y to go up and then x,y and x again..
Thanks.

**Update:**
The code that helped me make a path animation is down here.
I tried to make a ratio formula between the emulator's screen dimension and any other phone:

```
metrics = new DisplayMetrics();   //Get the screen dimensions
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels; //Initiate screen dimensions
    widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;

    ratioX = heightPixels/1080;//set the ratios
    ratioY = widthPixels/1794;

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(-100*ratioX,800*ratioY);
    path.lineTo(430*ratioX, 800*ratioY);
    path.lineTo(430*ratioX,180*ratioY);
    path.lineTo(1145*ratioX,180*ratioY);
    path.lineTo(1145*ratioX,800*ratioY);
    path.lineTo(1794*ratioX,800*ratioY);


    anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(soldier,"x","y",path);
    anim.setDuration(3500);
```

this worked just fine on the emulator, but it doesnt work well on my phone(the animation stops in the middle and it doesnt follow the background's path.

Comment: what path do you want it to move on?

Comment: Didnt notice the image wasnt uploaded, i added it

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator`, there are couple of `ObjectAnimator#of*()` methods that accept `Path` parameter

Comment: Thanks!! it worked, how can i make the corner turns "softer"?

Comment: use `Path#arcTo` in the corners

Comment: it doesnt work for me.. i read about it and didnt get it..
also, i edited the original question, i will be glad if you could look

Comment: you are not using `arcTo`: your corners are not smooth

Comment: Yeah i wrote that i tried to read about it and didnt succeed making the corners smooth